# How to load test a python script from Tsung?

Tags: python, load-testing, tsung

I am trying to check the performance of twemproxy tool with memcached servers. 
For application load test, I have used Tsung to check the RPS of APIs which will fetch data from DB through twemproxy. However, to confirm the individual performance of twemproxy, i have written an insert script in python which will insert key and value into memcached server through twemproxy. Similarly, there is a script to fetch the value of a particular key from memcached server.

Is there a way where I can load test this script using tsung?

Comment: How doess your script works ? Tsung can't run python code by itself, maybe you can run a wrapper and use your code through an API.

Comment: @Rodolphe: Based on my initial research, even i found that it may not be possible to run a python script directly from tsung. Hence, I am exploring tools such as Locust to do the same